# How to INSERT based on a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have these `INSERT` query:

```
$db->prepare("INSERT INTO
              events (post_id, table_code, other_id, user_id, author_id, date_time )
              VALUES (?      , 15        , ?       , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP()),
                     (?      , 15        , ?       , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP())
")->execute(array($answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id,
                  $answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ans_id));
```

As you see, query above inserts two rows into `events` table. Now I need to put a condition on the way of second row. I mean if `$condition` is *true* then inserts second rows, else it shouldn't insert second row. *(first row always should be inserted)*.

**Note:** `$condition` always is containing a boolean value.

Well, how can I put that condition on the way of second row inserting?

Comment: Couldn't you just do a second prepared statement?

Comment: @georaldc Yes I can .. And I'll do that if I be force ..! But I think there is an approach to I do that by one single `INSERT` query.

Comment: You don't have to program it in SQL you know, just make your script make that decision. You don't have to solve every problem in 1 line of code.

Comment: @Havenard I believe always shorter codes are better `:-)`

Comment: as long as the one line less in code does not cost 5 lines more in sql...
I believe always clearer codes are better :-)

Comment: @Stack I believe that's called "premature optimization" ;-) Plus, I've tried implementing some logic in SQL - trust me, it tends to get really messy really quick...

Comment: @fpierrat You are right *(kinda)* ..

Comment: @Stack In terms, yes, wrapping noise in a simplified solution makes a code better, because it makes it clean and readable. But blobbing as much as you can it as few lines as possible doesn't always agree with that criteria.

Comment: @Havenard You are totally right .. agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `insert select` statement like this:

```
$db
->prepare("INSERT INTO
             events (post_id, table_code, other_id, user_id, author_id, date_time )
             select ?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
              UNION ALL
             select ?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
               from (select 1) as a
              where 1=?
")->execute(array($answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id,
                  $answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ans_id,
                  ($yourCondition?1:0) ));
```

Comment: Nice ...! Just why not `UNION ALL` ? Because `UNION` tries to remove duplicates, and there isn't duplicate rows at all.

Comment: It depends on your requirement since I don't know it I use UNION that will avoid duplicates but if it is a must you can use it :)

Comment: Fine .. +1 ..! And my last question, I cannot pas `$yourCondition` directly? That variable always contains `true` or `false`. So is this condition mandatory `$yourCondition==true?1:0` ? I mean What's wrong with `true/false`? Why should I fill it with `0/1` ?

Comment: Yes of course you can pass it directly. It is just for your understanding. Since it is already a boolean you can use it as `$yourCondition?1:0` It is a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Ok, However I meant was this: **query:** `. . . where ?` and **php:** `, $yourCondition)`

Comment: Yes, you also can do that. But be aware that this is not something to all databases, MySQL accept it. I am used to provide queries that will work in every databases. Just a costume.

Answer (score 1):

Since the $condition is a php variable why not do it in PHP like so:

```
if ($condition === true) {
    $db->prepare($first_and_seccond_row);
} else {
    $db->prepare($first_row);
}
```

Comment: Autocorrect got PHP and turned it into Photoshop? ;)

Comment: Damn it. May the inventor of autocorrect restaurant in peace

Comment: Sorry I don't know English very well and I cannot understand your point ..! But I guess you are kidding `:)` *(based on that emoji in the end of your comment)*

Comment: Don't worry, the autocorrect turned php to Photoshop XD, it's better that you didn't notice in the first place

Comment: I saw it and I was like wtf :)

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with doing it in 2 queries?

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO
              events (post_id, table_code, other_id, user_id, author_id, date_time)
              VALUES (?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())");

$query->execute(array($answer_id1, $answer_id1, $author_ques_id1, $author_ans_id1));

if ($condition)
    $query->execute(array($answer_id2, $answer_id2, $author_ques_id2, $author_ans_id2));
```

Comment: It should be noted that I was doubt to accept your solution or that one. Your solution is really clean. Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can build query string and values array before preparing and executing.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO
          events (post_id, table_code, other_id, user_id, author_id, date_time )
          VALUES (?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
$values = array($answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id);
if ($condition) {
    $query .= ",(?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP())";
    $values = array_merge($values, array($answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ans_id);
}
$db->prepare($query)->execute($values);
```