# Is there any default table to I use it as an alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
$db
->prepare("INSERT INTO
             events (post_id, table_code, other_id, user_id, author_id, date_time )
             select ?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
              UNION ALL
             select ?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
               from (select 1) as a
              where 1=?
")->execute(array($answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id,
                  $answer_id, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ans_id,
                  ($yourCondition?1:0) ));
```

Please focus on this line:

```
from (select 1) as a
```

My query works as well and all fine.

I just remember I read somewhere there is a default-table-name *(something like `double`)* which I can use it instead of `(select 1) as a` in this case. Anybody knows what's that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are thinking of `dual`.  This is borrowed from Oracle.  So instead of:

```
select ?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
from (select 1) as a
```

You can write:

```
select ?, 15, ?, ?, ?, UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
from dual
```

This is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> DUAL is purely for the convenience of people who require that all
>   SELECT statements should have FROM and possibly other clauses. MySQL
>   may ignore the clauses. MySQL does not require FROM DUAL if no tables
>   are referenced.

I'm not sure this is true, though.  I think `from` may be needed with `where` and `group by` clauses.

Comment: About your last sentence I have to say yes, there is `where` clause *(as you see it in the question)*, but no my query doesn't have `group by` clause .. I have to use `group by`? why?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would use `GROUP BY` in when you're selecting a single row of constant data. But I think you're right that you need it if you have a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Stack But you could have used the other answer in your previous question, where you perform the second `INSERT` as a separate query, instead of this convoluted way to combine them.

Comment: Yes I'm using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846754/how-to-insert-based-on-a-condition#37846895) in reality. Now I'm just trying to develop my knowledge. Can you please tell me when exactly should I use `group by` when I want to insert a new row?

Comment: @Stack . . . I was just commenting that `from dual` is not purely for convenience, in the sense that a `from` clause is needed in other circumstances.

Comment: @Barmar You said *"... you need it if you have a `WHERE` clause"*. What *"it"* refers to? `group by`? So I need a `group by` in that query which is into the question? Because it has a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: "it" is a `FROM` clause. You need `FROM DUAL` if you want to have a `WHERE` clause. Basically, you need a `FROM` clause if you want to have any other clauses that come after it -- `WHERE`, `HAVING`, `GROUP BY`, etc.